# displaying top 6 payment field records as columns for each account

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I have table that contains an account field their respective last payments. 
eg.

```
acc | lastpayment
1111  100.00
1111  150.00
1111  110.00
1112  111.00
1113  200.00
1114  300.00
```

These records will have duplicates as it will contain accounts that have had multiple payments (eg. in the above top 3 records).

I want to display only the top 6 payments of each account and then show the table columns as

```
acc | lastpayment1 | lastpayment2 | lastpayment3 | lastpayment4 | lastpayment5 | lastpayment6
```

Is this possible?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: If an account has say 12 records, which 6 should be pivoted into the wide layout ? The first 6 (if sorted by date that would be the oldest), the last 6 (if sorted by date that would be the newest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `view` that selects the 'N' rows that you want, per group, then `TRANSPOSE` the view

```
data top6;
  set have;
  by acc;
  if first.acc the seq = 1; else seq + 1;
run;

proc transpose data=top6 out=want;
  by acc;
  var lastpayment;
run;
```

**or**

Create a data step view that contains an array and DOW loop

```
data want (keep=acc lastpayment1-lastpayment6) / view=want;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.acc);
    set have;
    by acc;
    array payments lastpayment1-lastpayment6;
    if _n_ <= dim(payments) then
      payments(_n_) = lastpayment;
  end;
run;
```